# How to improve `list.map { case 3 => 6; case i => i }`?

Tags: scala

This is a very simple Scala code, but I wonder if there is any way to improve it.

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

list.map {
  case 3 => 6
  case i => i
}
```

I just want to convert the item `3`, and keep others as what they are. The code is quite simple now, but I still feel the `case i => i` part is not so necessary.

Is there any way to improve it, so I can just provide the core logic `case 3 => 6`?

---

The solution I can think of is to define a custom function like:

```
def change(list: List[Int])(f: PartialFunction[Int, Int]): List[Int] = {
    list.map { item =>
        if (f.isDefinedAt(item)) f(item) else item
    }
}
```

Then:

```
change(list)({ case 3 => 6})
```

But I wonder if there is something already done this.

Comment: Something like this? `list.map(x => if (x==3) 6 else x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not especially amazing:

```
scala> val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala> val pf: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = { case 3 => 6 }
pf: PartialFunction[Int,Int] = <function1>

scala> list.map(pf.applyOrElse(_, identity[Int]))
res3: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 6, 4)
```

It actually cleans up your function a bit:

```
scala> def f(vs: List[Int])(pf: PartialFunction[Int, Int]) = vs map (pf.applyOrElse(_, identity[Int]))
f: (vs: List[Int])(pf: PartialFunction[Int,Int])List[Int]

scala> f(list) { case 3 => 6 }
res4: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 6, 4)
```

or

```
scala> def f(vs: List[Int])(pf: PartialFunction[Int, Int]) = vs map (pf orElse { case x => x })
f: (vs: List[Int])(pf: PartialFunction[Int,Int])List[Int]
```